# http or https from url

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee-6

Here's the scenario.

My Java web application has following path
https://www.mywebsite.com:9443/MyWebApp
Let's say there is a JSP file
https://www.mywebsite.com:9443/MyWebApp/protected/index.jsp
and I need to retrieve 
the above url
 within this JSP file.
I can retrive everything but i need to retrieve the https as well.
How can i retrive https in jsp file.

Comment: window.location.protocol

Comment: do i get it for all browsers? how to find if the protocol is http or https.

Comment: yeah it works for all browsers. to find which is which :  window.location.protocol == 'http:' or window.location.protocol == 'https:'

Comment: Please edit tags on this question: You are getting valid answers both for javascript and java (jps)

Answer (score 2):

```
string scheme = request.getscheme();
```

Comment: I need to get in jsp page and pass to servlet.

Comment: @user3363771 `request` is an implicit object in an jsp page

Comment: When i use getscheme it works for https only. How to i capture in jsp file and send it to the servlet.

Comment: you should have mentioned this that u need to send it to the servlet. In thaat case you can use split function in javascript and split using (:) colon.

Comment: and i think this should be an answer

Comment: Will request.getscheme(); returns both http ans https?